# How do i get base url in OctoberCMS?

Tags: octobercms

I want to show image in backend render list. For that how to get the path to show image. We have tried **base_path()** method.

But it gives me full path like "opt/lampp/htdocs/ashish/" but i want to get http://localhost/ashish

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In twig you can do:

```
{{ url('/') }}
```

Answer (score 7):

Please use  **Request::getBaseUrl()** for get base path like http://localhost/ashish

Comment: I am also trying with base_path() method.Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
Config::get('app.url')
```

but first you have to properly configure your base path in app/config.php

I think is more general and you can also force the https if you need it.

Comment: no need to configure the base path user this {{ url('/') }} or  Request::getBaseUrl() .

Answer (score 0):

This the way that I have tried & proved its working nicely when working with displaying images from media manager.

```
Config::get('cms.storage.media.path')
```